# Functional Isomer of Formic Acid is?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have read like ''Functional Isomers of Carboxilic Acids are Esters'', then my doubt is; What about Formic Acid?

Comment: Well, if you'll try to make a functional isomer of formic acid in the same manner, you'll end up with formic acid. Guess that makes it an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Note the image of acetic acid (top) and the image of the carboxylic structural isomer methyl formate (middle).  As you can see the bonding location of the proton and the methyl group switch between the structural isomers.  Note the image of formic acid (bottom).  If you switch a hydrogen and a hydrogen you still get formic acid.  Yes, structural isomers of carboxylic acids make esters, but formic acid does not have a structural isomer, so the rule does not apply.

[image: Acetic Acid] Acetic Acid
[image: Methyl Formate] Methyl Formate
[image: Formic Acid] Formic Acid